# Hiding Banner at a certain page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm currently attempting to hide the banner at a certain page. I have successfully hid the banner in all other pages except one with a page with a id. I have a dynamic folder named [content]

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const HIDDEN_BOARDLIST = ["/board/board_list"];
//this is successful 

const HIDDEN_BOARDDETAILS = [`board/${content}`].  
//this does not work 
//http://localhost:3000/board/620471f057aad9002de7f04f. I have to enter the id manually but since this is a dynamic, the id will change every time 

export default function Layout(props: ILayoutProps) {
  const router = useRouter();

  console.log(router.asPath);

  const isHiddenBoardList = HIDDEN_BOARDLIST.includes(router.asPath);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Header />
      {!isHiddenBoardList && <Banner />}
      <BodyWrapper>
        <Body>{props.children}</Body>
      </BodyWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useRouter` is a hook.

CSR

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'React';
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

interface ILayoutProps {
  //...
}

export default function Layout(props: ILayoutProps) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(router.asPath.includes('board/')) {
      setHidden(true);
    }
  }, [router.asPath]);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Header />
      {!hidden && <Banner />}
      <BodyWrapper>
        <Body>{props.children}</Body>
      </BodyWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Since this code is CSR, flickering may occur. `<Banner />` will disappear after being rendered.

If you don't want that, there is a way to pass the current `url` as `props` of the `<Layout />` component via `getServerSideProps`.

SSR

```
// pages/board/[id].tsx
import { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from 'next';
import Head from 'next/head';

interface Props {
  url: string;
}

const BoardPage: NextPage<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout {...props} />
    </>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { resolvedUrl } = context; //ex) /board/12345?id=12345

  return {
    props: {
      url: resolvedUrl ,
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
};
```

```
// components/Layout.tsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'React';
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

interface ILayoutProps {
  url: string;
  // ...
}

export default function Layout(props: ILayoutProps) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Header />
      {props.url.includes('board/') && <Banner />}
      <BodyWrapper>
        <Body>{props.children}</Body>
      </BodyWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

I hope these two kinds of code are helpful.